# Adding a zero to my month function

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

I want to use the today() function as a dynamic filter to show MM/YYYY as number format

So i want my filter to show =201601

But with my function i get 20161: `input(CATS(Year(TODAY()),Month(TODAY())), 6.)` =20161

Does anybody know how to show 201601 instead of 20161?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sas, but almost every tool can declare the format of output you wants, on Month(TODAY()) , is it possible to add 'MM'? Month(TODAY(),'MM') or something

Comment: The question is not clear.  Are you looking to display a date in yyyymm format or are you looking to filter records to a specific year and month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a format that will display a data in YYYYMM format.

```
put(today(),yymmn6.)
```

Did you intend to convert to a number instead of a character string?  If so then you could use the INPUT function as in your example.

```
input(put(today(),yymmn6.),6.)
```

You could even use the YYMMDDN format if YYMMN doesn't work for you, just read the first 6 digits.

```
input(put(today(),yymmddn8.),6.)
```

Or you could build the number arithmetically.

```
year(today())*100+month(today())
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the proper function:

```
put(today(), yymmn6.)
```